# Issue with array.remove in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to manage an array of lines, specifically lines, by removing certain lines under specific conditions. However, I've run into trouble with the array.remove operation, as it seems to not work as expected.

I've simplified my script to highlight the problem, but this issue is consistent in my more complex real script. I'll share the simplified version to illustrate the problem I'm encountering:

```
// Heikin-Ashi calculations 
haClose = (open+high+low+close)/4
haOpen = (open[1] + close[1])/2
haHigh = math.max(high, math.max(haOpen, haClose))
haLow = math.min(low, math.min(haOpen, haClose))
haColor = haClose >= haOpen ? color.green : color.red
// Detect color change 
colorChange = haColor != haColor[1]
// Array to store lines
var line[] lines = array.new_line(0)
// Draw line on color change  
if colorChange
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[1], haClose[1] >= haOpen[1] ? haHigh[1] : haLow[1], bar_index, haClose[1] >= haOpen[1] ? haHigh[1] : haLow[1], extend=extend.right)
    array.push(lines, newLine)
// Remove crossed lines
removeCrossedLines() =>
    tempLines = array.new_line(0)
    // Get line points
        x1 = line.get_x1(l)
        y1 = line.get_y1(l)
        x2 = line.get_x2(l)  
        y2 = line.get_y2(l)

    for i = 0 to array.size(lines) - 1
        line l = array.get(lines, i)

        // Check if crossed using high/low at x1/x2 bars (your existing code)
        if not isCrossed
            array.push(tempLines, l)

    // Update lines array (problematic part)
    lines = tempLines
lines

if array.size(lines) > 10
    lines := removeCrossedLines()
```

As you can see, I've tried to remove certain lines from the lines array within the removeCrossedLines function. However, this doesn't seem to work as expected. The lines array remains unchanged.

I've tried various approaches, including using a **temporary array, storing indexes, and then removing elements after the loop**. Unfortunately, nothing has resolved the issue. Since none of those worked I guess I have a more fundamental problem here but sadly I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary array is a good plan. You just need to remember to delete the line explicitly.

Try something like this:

```
removeCrossedLines() =>
    tempLines = array.new_line(0)

    for i = 0 to array.size(lines) - 1
        line l = array.get(lines, i)

        // Check if crossed using high/low at x1/x2 bars (your existing code)

        if not isCrossed
            array.push(tempLines, l)
        else
            line.delete(l)  // Delete the line if it has been crossed

    tempLines  // Return the temp array
```

Then in the global scope, you need to update your array when you call this function

```
if array.size(lines) > 10
    lines := removeCrossedLines()
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. I tried implementing the changes but I can't really check if the change is working in principle since there is now a study error: The study references too many candles in history. 

I tried limiting them with "max_bars_back = 400" but this had no effect. Do you now any solutions?

Comment: That is a different issue. Can't say anything without seeing your whole code.

Comment: Hey virtruvius, I updated the code that was missing. To keep the thread alive until I know if your fix worked or if the problem lies somewhere else I have not yet applied your changes to the code in the post. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested your fix on a higher timeframe and it worked. Thanks